# How to change location intervals with something like PUSH notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, geolocation, android-location

My app is able to track the user even if the app is in background or killed and send the currents lat and long to the server.
I am using FusedLocationApi for this with a PendingIntent. My question is how can i change the interval of LocationRequest if my app is not running in foreground ?

I want to do something like catch the PUSH notification which firebase provide and then change this intervals, but it's not possible.

It would drain too much battery if i set the intervals (setInterval,setFastestInterval and setPriority) to the most frecuency and HIGH_ACCURACY and only catch in the server some of this request, and then when i want to get more frecuency, catch all the location requests?

Is it possible to avoid making the client (the user smartphone) work like a server that wait for a notification, like firebase?

EDIT:
What i'm trying it seems to work but i still have the problem of comunication.
I create a service and 2 differents types of API FusedLocationServices and 1 work at the moment and the other just wait for a signal from the server to start sending location... And that's exactly what i want to know how to do in a good way. How to listening to the server continuously ?? There exists a way like the onMessageReceived of firebase??

Comment: you want to set two different time interval to get a location update when the app is running or killed?

Comment: what i want is that the app give me the location with some intervals and accuracy, but in some moment, i want to change to the best location and more frecuency interval. Like the google Android Device Manager.

Comment: you can first remove location updates and then reregister

Comment: But i am using IntentService, that i pass to google services as a PendingIntent. I understand what you suggest, but how can i catch from the server the request of changing location settings without opening the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i could handle this issue as i say, creating 2 differents LocationRequest, one running all the time when opening the app the first time with the necessary configuration and the other is created where i implement the  onMessageReceived of firebase.
I have to send a POST data-message (i use POSTMAN for this) to be sure that onMessageReceived is called and that's it!